# Lightswitch "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I get the following error when i try to save in my lightswitch application.
**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**

I have published the application to a different computer.

But when i publish it to the same computer on which it is developed, it works perfectly.
I think i am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means you're trying to use something not defined or not initialized at that moment.

If it works in you dev machine but not on the deployed machine; then it's highly possible that  you did something wrong with the deployment.

Try to debug and understand the difference between to configurations.
If you can't debug on the deployed computer, it would be better to write a log somewhere and understand which variable is giving you the error.

Comment: Hi, I  deployed the application in another machine. It worked perfectly too. Please help, this is really frustrating.

Comment: @PrabhathKarunakalage I couldn't understand, deployed perfectly or workin on the deployed machine perfectly?

Comment: I have 3 machines, working on the developed machine and one other machine. But not on the other machine.(Which we want it to run so badly)

Comment: then there must be a configuration dependent coding there, a parse for example, that depends on the current localization settings of the device running it.

Comment: Thankyou for your time but i tried a new project with only one table and a new data screen with no code typed. Still getting the error.

Comment: np, please refer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/cc71cb2c-739a-4d96-be49-af2e742073db) link and check if the machine supports the minimum requirements.

Comment: It supports all the requirements. Is there any particular software that would cause silverlight to crash?

Comment: I don't know about it, please forward the question to [Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/threads)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, difference cause apparently, but this article discusses the issue and solution.

[Web Deployment Woes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/597cc051-1e26-4601-bd77-8dd39b091721/web-deployment-woes?prof=required)